# Populate "about me" from Network Profile instead of oldest site account upon joining a new site

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-accounts, network-profile

Related:

- [Don't copy "about me" from my oldest account when I join a community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290414/350567)
- [Use another profile other than the oldest when joining new community or site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233887/350567)

This is basically the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) version of the second link above.

Can we have our profiles synched from our Network Profile (or the site we've chosen to display as NP) instead of the oldest site profile?

---

Personally, my oldest site profile is SO, which I update frequently, and is usually not suitable on other sites. My NP, OTOH, is specifically written as

> My profile on Meta Stack Exchange: <link to my MSE profile>

This is, IMO, suitable to be displayed on an arbitrary SE site as my "about me".

Problem is, now I have various old versions of my SO "about me" scattered around on individual sites I joined from time to time (usually for flagging spam - not relevant here). It'd be nice had they been the above "designated profile".

Comment: We're working to eliminate the underlying profile on stackexchange.com, at which point it would likely revert to auto-syncing from the oldest profile or just not have bio information displayed at all.

Answer (score 4):

I see from animuson's comment that the network profile is going to go away eventually.  Otherwise this would be the ideal approach: we can intentionally *choose* what to show on the network profile and are presumably doing it with *the network* in mind, so it's a better choice than the oldest account.  (My oldest account is Mi Yodeya, where I've written a profile tuned to the site.  That's *never* going to be a meaningful profile on any other site.  And yet it's on a bunch of them because I didn't explicitly clean them up.)

Since we can't use the network profile and we do want to preserve the *option* to copy a profile (I suspect most people don't vary them like you and I do), it'd be great to have the option to copy from a *specific site*.  When creating an account, give people an option like this:

[image: mockup: site chooser]

Leaving the box unchecked means don't copy anything (start with a blank profile), or skip the checkbox and add "none" to the list.

After account creation, ideally this would be available under "edit profile".  Currently we can edit a profile and *push* it to *all other sites*, which is a bad idea for this use case.  This change would give people a way to *pull* from a *specific profile*.